# SSRS Chart with multiple labels for a single data point

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report with a chart that has a data point that 3 different sets of data share, so naturally when I show labels that data point has 3 labels. I would like to reduce this to just 1 label, is this possible? 
[image]

Comment: Not exactly sure what you need, but have you looked into the [`First()` function?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-first-function)

Comment: I was fooling around with the previous function, which would eliminate 1 label... but that might work.

Comment: I kinda have it with this =IIF(Previous(Fields!DateEnds.Value)=LAST(Fields!DateEnds.Value),"",FormatDateTime(Fields!DateEnds.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate))

Comment: Perhaps you can look into grouping on that date. Once you do that you will have distinct dates.

Comment: used row_number in sql and in label expression IIF =1 then ... works good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn’t a way to suppress/limit labels in this scenario using the UI in SSRS. The only method is to utilize a “custom” SQL command as described in the comments.